# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'cuda'

Tags: python, pytorch

It's my first time to use stack overflow. Thanks for your help!
Recently, I'm learning Deep-Learning with Pytorch. When I finished the DataSet and DataLoader, I got some trouble in writing train function. It show me that:

```
<ipython-input-16-e211160f5ce8> in <module>()
      5 total = 0
      6 for id, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
----> 7   inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()
      8   optimizer.zero_grad()
      9   outputs = net(inputs)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'cuda'
```

My code is here:

```
for id, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
  inputs, labels = inputs.cuda(), labels.cuda()
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  outputs = net(inputs)
  loss = self.criterion(outputs, labels)
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```

The Dataloader return image and labels, the image's type is numpy.array and the labels' type is tuple. I can not do anything to the parameters inputs and labels. I don't find answer in Google. Thanks for help and endure my English and code.

For more details:
My dataset is Stanford Cars, and I use it to achieve image classification. 
It just a simple code, I don't know what's worry with it. Or you can give me some advice to learn Pytorch, Thanks:)
torch                    1.5.0+cu101 
torchvision              0.6.0+cu101

Comment: I guess you're using PyTorch with CUDA supported?

Comment: `print(inputs)` and `print(labels)` as a first statement inside your loop will show the error. `inputs` and `labels` might not be what you think they should be.

Comment: Yes, and I have try to use CPU to train, but it fail.Like this:
`      9   optimizer.zero_grad()
     10   outputs = net(inputs)
---> 11   loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     12   loss.backward()
     13   optimizer.step()`
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'`

Comment: For Jan, I just try print, and I have got every batch's image array and its labels, like this:
`          ...,
          [ 0.8039,  0.8039,  0.8039,  ...,  0.8039,  0.8039,  0.8039],
          [ 0.7882,  0.7882,  0.7882,  ...,  0.7882,  0.7882,  0.7882],
          [ 0.7961,  0.7961,  0.7961,  ...,  0.7961,  0.7961,  0.7961]]]])
('41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '41', '42', '42', '42', '42')`

Comment: Well, I konw it. I turn the tuple into np.array, then turn the array into tensor. It works. Thanks for everyone help!
`  labels = np.array(labels, int)
  labels = torch.Tensor(labels)
  inputs = torch.Tensor(inputs)
  inputs = inputs.cuda()
  labels = labels.cuda()`